# Dictionary in controller resets out of the blue resuting in NPE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

For some reason my Dictionary seems to reset to `0` (no elements), every time I try to access it with my `ActionResult Details()` method. I’m not really sure why this happens and what I can do to prevent this from happening. I’ve tried changing the access modifiers, but that has lead to no success, I’ve also searched several forums but it’s hard to find a similar issue. I’m sure it’s something easy that I’m just overseeing, if anyone would be able to help out, I would greatly appreciate it.
I’ve debugged it to see if data actually gets added to the dictionary. Seems like it’s being added just fine.

```
using TransactionImporter.Factory;
using TransactionImporter.WebUI.Models;
using TransactionImpoter.Domain;

namespace TransactionImporter.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class DownloadController : Controller
    {
        private IUploadDetailLogic uploadDetailLogic = UploadDetailFactory.CreateLogic();
        private IExporterLogic exporterLogic = ExporterFactory.CreateLogic();
        private IUserLogic userLogic = UserFactory.CreateLogic();
        public IDictionary<int, DownloadModels> IdModelDictionary = new Dictionary<int, DownloadModels>();

        // GET: Download
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<UploadDetail> uploadDetailList = uploadDetailLogic.UploadDetailList();
            List<DownloadModels> downloadableList = new List<DownloadModels>();
            foreach (UploadDetail upload in uploadDetailList)
            {
                User user = userLogic.GetUserById(upload.UserId);
                DownloadModels model = new DownloadModels(upload.UploadId, upload.UserId, user.Username,
                    upload.StartTimeUpload.ToString(), upload.FileName, Convert.ToInt32(upload.FileSize));

                downloadableList.Add(model);
                IdModelDictionary.Add(upload.UploadId, model);
            }
            return View(downloadableList);
           }

        // GET: Download/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View(IdModelDictionary[id]);
        }
```

DownloadModels:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TransactionImporter.WebUI.Models
{
    public class DownloadModels
    {
        public DownloadModels(int uploadId, int userId, string uploadedOn, string fileName, int fileSize)
        {
            UploadId = uploadId;
            UserId = userId;
            UploadedOn = uploadedOn;
            FileName = fileName;
            FileSize = fileSize;
        }
        public DownloadModels(int uploadId, int userId, string username, string uploadedOn, string fileName, int fileSize)
        {
            UploadId = uploadId;
            UserId = userId;
            Username = username;
            UploadedOn = uploadedOn;
            FileName = fileName;
            FileSize = fileSize;
        }
        public DownloadModels() { }

        public int UploadId { get; private set; }
        public string UploadedOn { get; private set; }
        public string FileName { get; private set; }
        public int FileSize { get; private set; }
        public int UserId { get; private set; }
        public string Username { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here’s the Index that calls the `ActionResult Details()` method in the controller every time a user mouse-overs the details href. Seeing as the Dictionary decides to reset itself to `0`, every time I hover over the details, I get an NPE because it can’t find the key I’m looking for because there is no data in the dictionary.

```
@model IEnumerable<TransactionImporter.WebUI.Models.DownloadModels>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Uploads</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UploadId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UploadedOn)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadedOn)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onmouseover="ShowDetails(@item.UploadId)">Details</a> |
                @Html.ActionLink("Download-EU", "DownloadEu", new { id = item.UploadId, controller = "Download" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UploadId, controller = "Download" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div class="col-md-6" id="MyDetails">

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>

        var ShowDetails = function (id) {

            var detailsDiv = $('#MyDetails');
            $.get('/Download/Details/', { id: id }, function (data) {
                detailsDiv.html(data);
            });
        };
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only add to your `IdModelDictionary` object in the `Index()` action.  But then you don't do anything with it.

Later, you try to reference it in your `Details()` action, but without adding anything to it first.

The point you're missing is that these actions are entirely unrelated and stateless.  Every HTTP request to this controller results in a new instance of the controller being created.  So the controller instance which executed `Index()` (and populated its `IdModelDictionary` object), and the controller instance which executed `Details()` are *different instances* of the controller object.  By the time the second instance is created, the first one is long gone.

In order to retain data across multiple HTTP requests, that data needs to be persisted somewhere.  A database is a common place to persist data.  Other options include, but are not limited to:

- The page (so data is available client-side)
- Session state
- Application cache
- `static` properties
- File system
- Other caching systems (which likely internally use a database of some sort)

Each has its pro's and con's, you can weigh the options and make a decision.  Probably the most common and least perilous approach would be to store your data in a database.  In an `Index()` action one would generally display a summary list of the data, and in a `Details()` action one would generally display the details of a specific record from the data.  Each action would separately query the database.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I don't know why I did not thought of this myself. Still very new to ASP.NET and programming in general. Appreciate it.